# Access RDD elements by index

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD as below and would like to access the elements within each row by its index number in a loop. Is this possible?

```
(98,(344,(Dead Man Walking (1995),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
(50,(501,(Richard III (1995),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)))
(1,(321,(Toy Story (1995),0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

So far, I have come up with the below code

```
val combgenr = mvnmcnt.map(x => (x._2._2.productIterator.foreach{
var n = 4
i => (
if (i == "1") {println((x._1.toInt,x._2._1.toInt,x._2._2._1),n)
})
n += 1
}))
```

But the I get an extra line in my result(below), the reason for which I don't know.

```
((98,344,Dead Man Walking (1995)),13)
()
((50,501,Richard III (1995)),13)
((50,501,Richard III (1995)),22)
((50,501,Richard III (1995)),23)
()
((1,321,Toy Story (1995)),8)
((1,321,Toy Story (1995)),9)
((1,321,Toy Story (1995)),10)
()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What output do you want an what have you tried so far ?

Comment: The RDD above has to be matched(if it contains "1" in any of the last 19 fields) with another RDD, which contains the movie genre. For e.g. from the first row - "(1,(321,(Toy Story (1995),0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))" index numbers 5,6 & 7 from 3rd tuple has "1" which means genre's - Comdey, Crime, Drame respectively from another RDD. I don't have a meaningful code to post here yet!